# How run multiple php files in one link?

Tags: php

I've got three PHP files:

```
www.mywebsite.com/step1.php
www.mywebsite.com/step2.php
www.mywebsite.com/step3.php
```

Right now, a user can go to `step2.php` by directly entering the URL in the address bar, which I do not want to happen. How do I make all the links above only work in one web page ensuring the users go through the entire process from `step1.php` to `step3.php` without skipping?

Comment: add a session variable

Comment: after visiting step1, add a session variable `visited_1` and set it to true, then check this in step2.

Answer (score 0):

Create a session variable on `step1.php` and `POST` it. check the session variable on `step2.php` & `step3.php`, if session variable not there redirect back on `step1.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by SOFT1234 is right. In addition to it,

- Create a common session variable in ( $_SESSION['something'] ), initial value = 0
- At the end of step1.php change its value to 1 and redirect to step2.php
- At step2.php check if the value of the session variable is 1 else redirect to step1.php. Similarly at the end of step2.php change its value to 2 and redirect to step3.php.
- Here in step3.php, first check if the value of session variable is 1, if so redirect user to step2.php (User has passed step1).
- If value is 2, stay in step3.php (User has passed step2).
- If the value is not 2 or 1, redirect the user to step1.php (User has not passed anything).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the step1.php file add the following code at top:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['step']=1;

//rest of the code
```

In the step2.php file add the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['step']) && $_SESSION['step'] != 1)
{
 header('location:step1.php')
}else{

    $_SESSION['step']=2;
}

//rest of the code
```

Similarly in the step3.php file add the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['step']) && $_SESSION['step'] != 2)
{
 header('location:step2.php')
}else{

    $_SESSION['step']=3;
} 

//rest of the code
```